# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}' в блоке ajax()

Tags: jquery

Помогите понять почему в консоли ошибка **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'**

Ругается на фигурную скобку в строке: **$.ajax({**

Скрипт на странице один:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 

 $('body').on('click', '.c_invite', function(){
  
  m_id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
  
  if(confirm("Отправить приглашение в команду?")) 
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:'/zzz/action/send_invite.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{m_id:m_id,t_id:<?=$user_team_id;?>},
    success:function(response) {
     alert(response);
     //спрятать значок приглашения
     $('tr#'+m_id+' td .c_invite').css('display', 'none');
    }
   })
  
  }

 });
 
}); // end document ready 

</script>
```

Comment: какой приходит ответ?

Comment: скрипт не выполняется из за ошибки

Comment: Синтаксис верный, думаю, дело в том, что "приходит" от PHP тут - `<?=$user_team_id;?>`. Можете предоставить код с уже подставленным значением?

Comment: вы оказались правы. в переменной ничего не было.

Comment: добавил ковычки '<?=$user_team_id;?>' и стало работать